# Reading and writing from a mySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to create a java program which can connect to an online mySQL database. I have done some research and figured out that I should use an online mySQL database. In java, I understand there is a JDBC library for connecting to databases. How can I connect to the database online with reading and writing to it? I am looking into using the Google Cloud SQL. It says to connect to it like any other mySQL Database.

Google Cloud SQL:[Website](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external)

Basically, my main question is: How can I connect to an online mySQL database with reading and writing to it from a java application?

**Edit**: Also is there any example for reading and writing to the database, not just how to connect?

Comment: Have you tried this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/?

Comment: I read up on it, and that is if I am using the Google App Engine and running my application in the cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a connector, you can find at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
Then you install, and next you should put in your build path, if you are using the eclipse, go right click on your project folder, properties, java build path libraries adn add external jar (the jar must be C:\Program Files \MySQL\MySQL Connector as mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar ), next go order and export, select the jar imported and save.

After that you have installed the api to connect to the database for mysql

```
String mysql_jdb_driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";          // the connector for the database
String mysql_db_url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/notas";       // url to connect, in this case is local but you can connect to an ip
String mysql_db_user = "root";                              // DB user name MYSQL
String mysql_pass = "";                                     //DB password

try{                                                                //try to connect to the DB
    Class.forName(mysql_jdb_driver).newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(mysql_db_url,mysql_db_user, mysql_pass );
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ...");//put your select here
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT ...");//put insert, delete here

}
catch(Exception ex){                                
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally                                                              // always close the connecttion
{
    conn.close();           
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see here there is an example on connecting to the database. How can I read and write the data?

Comment: You must do by the Insert and Select for example you have a string name and password, you should something like: stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT `columnName` `columPass` VALUES ( `" + name + "` , `" + pass + "`);" );

For the select you can do something like:
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `tablename` ");
while(rs.next()){ name = rs.getString(1); pass = rs.getString(2);}

Answer (score 2):

as Roman suggested, all you need  is in the link. If your application is not on the App Engine, just use include the mysql driver on the project and create the connection. Take a look at this: [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)